# How to turn a Python script, which uses third-party packages and a JSON-file, into a standalone executable?

Tags: python

I have a Python script that uses (1) several third-party packages installed in a Conda environment and (2) a JSON-file to access a certain web-API. I want to turn it into an executable that would run on my colleague's machine (Mac). That machine also has Conda installed.

My co-worker is not tech-savy, so I want my solution to be as self-contained as possible. It's also not just one case – my goal is to develop a workflow for the future.

I guess, I need a way to somehow pack all third-party code into a single folder so that I can just pass it to him – no need for environment management and manual installation of packages.

Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: Ok, I've just stumbled upon this: https://conda.github.io/conda-pack/. Maybe, that will solve my problem.

Comment: You could also use `pyinstaller`

Comment: If you find the solution, please post it as an answer and mark it as such, to help others.

Comment: @AbhigyanJaiswal I tried but didn't like it for now. Working on an alternative

Comment: @AbhigyanJaiswal Ok, it seems I did it with PyInstaller :)

Comment: @RufusVS Yeah, I'll do it